# Iterative decrement from A to B within n steps

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

I have an initial value `A` (with `A > 1` e.g `100`) and I want to reach the value `1` after `n` iterative decrements by a percentage `x`. More precisely, I want to find the value `n` that given:

```
A = 100
repeat for n times:
    A = A * x
```

produces `A=1` at the end of the loop. How can I calculate this value?

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is no $n$ that actually produces $A = 0$.  For example, with $A = 1$ and a decrement of $50\%$, $A$ attains the sequence of values $1 \mapsto \frac 12 \mapsto \frac 14 \mapsto \frac 18 \mapsto \cdots $

Comment: You are correct. I updated the question

Comment: Your change doesn't help.  Again, we're never going to hit $0$.  For example, with $A = 2$ and a $50\%$ decrement, we have 
$$
2 \mapsto 1 \mapsto \frac 12 \mapsto \frac 14 \mapsto \frac 18 \mapsto \cdots
$$

Comment: That's why I changed to reach 1 rather than 0

Comment: That's not what your question says

Comment: My bad, I did modified only half of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value of $n$ for which we'll have $A \leq 1$ will be given by
$$
n = \left \lceil -\frac{\log(A)}{\log(x)} \right \rceil
$$

Comment: That works! Thanks!